# What's the fastest way to check if a URL already exists in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I have a `varchar(255)` column where I store URL's in a MySQL database.  This column has a unique index.

When my crawler encounters a URL, it has to check the database to see if that URL already exists.  If it exists, the crawler selects data about that entry.  If it does not exist, the crawler adds the url.  I currently do this with the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, junk
        FROM files
        WHERE url = '$url'";
$results = $this->mysqli->query( $sql );

// the file already exists in the system
if( $results->num_rows > 0 )
{
    // store data to variables
}

// the file does not exists yet... add it
else
{

    // insert new file
    $sql = "INSERT INTO files( url )
            VALUES( '$url' )";
    $results = $this->mysqli->query( $sql );

}
```

I realize there are lots of ways to do this.  I've read that using a MySQL if/else statement could speed this up.  Can someone explain how MySQL would handle that differently, and why that may be faster?  Are there other alternatives I should test?  My crawlers are doing a lot of checking like this, and speeding up this process could be a significant speed boost for my system.

Comment: You could try setting up a prepared statement to do the URL query.

Comment: *cough* hash *cough* (there are similar questions on SO; assumes only need to strict equality tests)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, URLs are going to get much longer than `varchar(256)`.

Second of all, because they're that long you don't want to do string compares, it gets **very** slow as the table grows. Instead, create a column with a hash value and compare that.

You should index the hash column, of course.

As for the actual insert, an alternative is to put a unique constraint on the hash. Then do your inserts blindly, allowing SQL to reject the dupes. (But you'll have to put an exception handler into your code, which has its own overhead.)

Comment: i've read that mysql searches on a hash of varchars when you index them.  there is an index on this column already, so this is redundant i think.

Answer (score 0):

Considering not using transactions, to insert a new row if an old row does not exist by the WHERE condition, you can use:

```
"INSERT INTO files( url ) VALUES ( $url ) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM files WHERE url = $url );"
```

I can't think of a "one-line-commond" to select and insert at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the insert first and check for success(affected_rows), then select. If you check first, and then do the insert, the possibility exists that the url got inserted during that small time window. And, you would need to add more code to handle this situation.